# How to redirect print function of a called method

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm calling a method that happens to print a lot to the console. How do I override the print statements? For example,

```
import whatever

def upper(text):
     print(text.upper())
def main():
     whatever()
```

How could I pass what is printed by the whatever() function into the upper() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) for this:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

import whatever

def main():
    with StringIO() as f, redirect_stdout(f):
        whatever()
        text = f.getvalue()
```

Now `text` will contain whatever was printed by the call to `whatever()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. The issue is that I need every line printed by the whatever() function to be processed in real time, so I pass text to a function with every iteration. I'm receiving the following error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. To clarify, I want to redirect everything printed by whaterver(), but while the function is running, line by line

Comment: @JasonHakakha the `StringIO` object gets closed after the `with` block exits; you can just declare `f = StringIO()` beforehand instead if you want to keep it open. However, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "in real time" and "every iteration" -- maybe if you post more of your real code it'll make things clearer. Is there some multithreading involved?